# Passing parameters in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I need to pass parameters in Spark SQL.
For example, I have the below query as
Val timestamp =spark.sql("select timestamp from tablea ")
Now, i have another query to pass this timestamp in where class
Spark.sql(s"select col1 from tableb where timestamp = '$timestamp' ").

But the above query returns mismatched expression error.
Can someone please suggest a solution

Comment: What is the value of timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

In this case query `val timestamp =spark.sql("select timestamp from tablea ")` return a new dataframe which looks like `timestamp : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timestamps: bigint]`. That is the reason why you can't pass it into the next select query.

I can see at least two ways of solving that problem:

1) Use join:

`spark.sql("select a.col1 from tableb a join tablea b on a.timestamp = b.timestamp")`

2) Convert timestamp dataframe to string:

```
val timestampString = "("+myTimestamp.collect.map(r => r(0)).mkString(",")+")"
spark.sql(s"select col1 from tableb where timestamp = $timestampString ")
```